# z-index of spectrum color picker not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs

anyone please help me, I use spectrum color picker in popup modal, but the spectrum color picker is behind of popup modal, I want color picker in front of popup modal. I use z-index but not working, I define z-index: 9999999 !important;, but after build project use gulp build, value of z-index to be z-index: 9 !important;, I use angularJS.

How to solve this problem ?
thanks.

[image]

Comment: Post the full code, using fiddle/snippet.

Comment: please add your code,else we can just predict it

Comment: sorry, too much if all the code, which I display the html and css

Comment: <spectrum-colorpicker class="colorpicker-symbol-option"
    format="'hex'" options="{ preferredFormat: 'name',
        showInput: true, showInitial: true,  showButtons: false }"
    ng-model="vm.throughputRange.singleSymbol.color" 
    ng-change="vm.updateSymbolColor(vm.throughputRange.singleSymbol.color)"></spectrum-colorpicker>

Comment: sp-container {
 z-index: 9999999 !important;
 border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
 background-color: #FBFDFF;
 border: solid 1px rgb(204, 204, 204);
 padding: 0; 
}

Comment: Instead of appending details in comment, please edit your question.

Comment: post your code in a working plunkr  and update it to the code which will help to solve your issue, without this screen shot and code in the comments it will not be helpful for us to work on.

Comment: ok. .thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make a guess and assume that you're using cssnano to minify your CSS. There's a little configuration option that you should set to `true` to avoid z-index rebasing: http://cssnano.co/options/#optionssafe-bool.

In your `gulpfile.js`, you need to set this option, like so: `cssnano({safe: true})`.

Comment: @johnHarry if it helps, you should accept answer by clicking the button